# Jinja macro doesn't see value passed to render_template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

On certain pages I want my form drop down to be in a specific order and in other pages in a default order.  When passing in a specific order from my app, my macro in `form.html` doesn't seem to see it.  `dropdown` is never used, the template always displays the global data instead.  Why is this happening?

`form.html`:

```
    {% if dropdown %}
        <select name="status">
        {% for option in dropdown %}
              <option value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    {% else %}
        <select name="status">
        {% for option in global_add_links_data()[0] %}
              <option value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    {% endif %}
```

`app.py`:

```
dropdown = [
    'Placed',
    'Review Not Started',
    'Review Passed',
    'Review Failed',
    'Contacted Pending',
    'Contacted Failed',
    'No Contacts',
    'No Reply',
    'Not Interested'
]
dropdown.insert(0, dropdown.pop(dropdown.index(link_status)))
return render_template('view.html', dropdown=dropdown)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not rendering `form.html` directly, you are rendering `view.html` and importing `form.html`.  [When importing other templates, the template context is not passed by default.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import-context-behavior)  `dropdown` is local to the `view.html` context, so it is always undefined in `form.html`.

To import a template with context, you use the `with context` keywords.

```
{% from "form.html" render_form with context %}
```

---

A better, more explicit way to handle this is to just pass `dropdown` as an argument to the macro.  This is more efficient, because as the docs above mention, imports are normally cached for performance, but using `with context` disables that.

```
{% macro render_form(form, dropdown=None) -%}
    {% if dropdown %}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

```
{% from "form.html" import render_form %}
{{ render_form(form, dropdown) }}
```